# Eigenstate thermalization in chaotic Floquet systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, many-body, ergodicity

### Background

In closed time-independent Hamiltonian systems, the eigenstate thermalization hypothesis (ETH) states, roughly speaking, that energy eigenstates "look thermal". More precisely, the ETH is a statement about the matrix elements of local operators in the energy eigenbasis, i.e.

$$\langle E_{m} | O | E_{n} \rangle = f_{O}(\overline{E}) \delta_{mn} + e^{-S(\overline{E})/2} g_{O}(\overline{E},\omega) R_{mn}, \tag{1}$$

where $\overline{E} = (E_{m} + E_{n})/2$, $\omega = E_{n} - E_{m}$, $S(E)$ is the thermodynamic entropy at energy $E$, $R_{mn}$ is a random variable with zero mean and unit variance, and $f_{O}$ and $g_{O}$ are smooth functions which in general depend on the local operator $O$.

This has the consequence that we expect that for a Hamiltonian $H$ obeying the ETH, its energy eigenstates (in the bulk of the spectrum) should satisfy

$$\langle E | O | E\rangle \approx \mathrm{Tr}\left[\dfrac{e^{-\beta H}}{Z} O \right]\tag{2}$$

for all local operators $O$, where $Z = \mathrm{Tr}\left[e^{-\beta H}\right]$, and the inverse temperature $\beta$ is chosen so that the mean energy in the thermal state is equal to $E$.

The appearance of the random variable in the ETH helps make the connection between chaotic quantum systems and random matrices --- the eigenspectrum of a chaotic Hamiltonian is typically well described by the random matrix ensemble consistent with its symmetries.

For periodically-driven (Floquet) systems, we can also define a notion of chaos through this connection to random matrix theory. For the purposes of this question, let us define a chaotic Floquet unitary $U$ as one whose eigenspectrum is well described by the circular unitary ensemble.

Furthermore, let us say that a unitary $U$ is *local* if it can be written as the time-evolution of a local Hamiltonian for unit time,

$$U = \mathcal{T}\exp\left(-i \int_{0}^{1} H(t) \mathrm{d}t\right).$$

### Questions

1. Is it possible to define a version of the ETH for chaotic Floquet systems in terms of matrix elements of local operators in Floquet eigenstates, similar to Eqs 1 and 2? Naively I would have thought that the lack of energy conservation in Floquet systems means you might get the infinite temperature version of these statements.
2. If the answer to question 1 does indeed involve some infinite temperature version of the ETH, does this preclude the possibility of spontaneous symmetry breaking in eigenstates of chaotic local Floquet unitaries?